# Text block over image with background the same length of the image

Tags: html, css, textblock

I'm trying to create a text block with transparent background which is the same width as the image. However if I just add padding to the header then some may overlap or not be long enough due to the varying length in text.

Currently looks like this: http://puu.sh/sdBCX/994cc31da8.png

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
        <div class="artist-grid">
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                 <img id="#artistTile" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300">

                 <h3><span>BASSNECTAR</span></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img id="#artistTile" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300">

                 <h3><span>DATSIK</span></h3>                    
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img id="#artistTile" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300">

                 <h3><span>CHAINSMOKERS</span></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img id="#artistTile" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300">

                 <h3><span>ZEDS DEAD</span></h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
        </div>          
</div>
</div>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 244px;
    width: 100%
}

h3 span {
    color: white;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}

.artist-grid {
    padding-top: 22px;
}

#artistTile {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: the code you posted not reproduces what you describe...

Comment: Link:-https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(image.jpg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.